# Core Data: handle the case when iCloud turns off / on

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, icloud

I am implementing iCloud support in my Core Data app (iOS 7 only, not released yet, iCloud support will be from Day I). I've checked out WWDC 2013 207 session about changes in iCloud and I am really glad to see the improvements (I had some previous experience with iCloud too).

Things are working really great. However, I am not sure how to handle the case when user enables or disables iCloud from system preferences — this results to creating new `.sqlite` files in another directory and therefore user data loss.

Here's how I implement persistent store adding:

```
- (void) addPersistentStoreToCoordinator {

    NSMutableDictionary *options = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [options setObject:@YES forKey:NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption];
    [options setObject:@YES forKey:NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption];

    NSURL *iCloud = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil];

    if (iCloud) {
         [options setObject:@"ABC123~com~myapp~myapp" forKey:NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey];
    }

    NSError* error;

// the only difference in this call that makes the store an iCloud enabled store
// is the NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey in options.

    [persistentStoreCoordinator_ addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                          configuration:nil
                                                    URL:self.storeURL
                                                options:options
                                                  error:&error];
}

- (NSURL *)storeURL {

    NSURL *documentsDirectory = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                                                                       inDomain:NSUserDomainMask
                                                              appropriateForURL:nil
                                                                         create:YES
                                                                          error:NULL];

    return [documentsDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyApp.sqlite"];
}
```

How do I save data from Core Data when user switches off/on iCloud preference in the settings?

(Side note: I've managed to manually handle the case when iCloud goes from state `[OFF]` > `[ON]` — fetching all data from old Core Data, then saving these NSManagedObject subclasses to newly created Core Data with iCloud enabled. However, this code is very app-specific (and pretty unstable). I am looking for more generic solutions).

Thanks

Comment: If you are still stuck with this take a look at this link for migrating core data files when user changes iCloud settings. http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/uimanageddocument-icloud-integration/

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same questions and found this https://gist.github.com/mluisbrown/7015953 .  Works perfectly for me now.

Comment: This code snippet is great and it helps to set up a Core Data stack with enabled iCloud, but it doesn't solve the issue I am describing. Try to create some data inside your app, then turn off iCloud in the settings (iCloud -> Documents & Data -> Your app) and I am pretty sure your created data will disappear.

Comment: I have found that this solution does in fact persist the data on the device in both scenarios.  With iOS 7 there is a local store that is transparently managed for you in the event that iCloud is not enabled, not reachable or if there is no iCloud even set up on the device.  I didn't think it could be this easy either, but it worked for me.